# ASP.NET Web Api > Stop Action when validation error happens

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a Web API project. I use `System.Web.Http.ApiController` as the base for my controller

```
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;
using project.Models;

namespace project.Controllers
{
    public class DemoController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/demo/submit")]
        public  object Post([FromBody] FormDataModel test)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

While my model is

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace server.Models
{
    public class FormDataModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone is required")]
        [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")]
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I'm sending an invalid POST request - the `Post` action is still executed. I'm able to track invalid requests with `ModelState.IsValid` but it seems like a redundant step, since I will always want my actions to stop execution with the same form of response if the validation fails.

Is there a standard way for managing validation failure for the whole controller / app in a single place?

Thanks!

Comment: You continue processing in the action but return the appropriate status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a ActionFilter I use to do just what you are asking

```
public class ModelStateValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Then just register it as a global handler

```
public static class FilterConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new ModelStateValidationAttribute());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this using ActionFilters. Check this excellent article:

https://smellyc0de.wordpress.com/2017/08/23/web-api-2-centralised-model-state-validation/